# 5g Tethering device not recognized in ifconfig - Ubuntu 18.04.03

Tags: networking, drivers, android, usb-modem, tethering

I've had a problem for two days now with my cellular router. It acts as a Android phone and I need to use USB tethering to share its connection to my NVIDIA Jetson Nano. I think I've tried most of the solutions on the web but nothing is helping.

I know that the tethering works because I've tried it on an other computer running Ubuntu 18.04.02. I can also share the internet connection over USB tethering from my HUAWEI Mate 20 to my NVIDIA Jetson.

**lsusb -v**

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 05c6:9024 Qualcomm, Inc. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
bLength                18
bDescriptorType         1
bcdUSB               3.20
bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
bDeviceSubClass         0 
bDeviceProtocol         0 
bMaxPacketSize0         9
idVendor           0x05c6 Qualcomm, Inc.
idProduct          0x9024 
bcdDevice            4.14
iManufacturer           1 
iProduct                2 
iSerial                 3 
bNumConfigurations      1
Configuration Descriptor:
bLength                 9
bDescriptorType         2
wTotalLength          128
bNumInterfaces          3
bConfigurationValue     1
iConfiguration          4 
bmAttributes         0x80
  (Bus Powered)
MaxPower              224mA
Interface Association:
  bLength                 8
  bDescriptorType        11
  bFirstInterface         0
  bInterfaceCount         2
  bFunctionClass        239 Miscellaneous Device
  bFunctionSubClass       4 
  bFunctionProtocol       1 
  iFunction               7 
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        0
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass       239 Miscellaneous Device
  bInterfaceSubClass      4 
  bInterfaceProtocol      1 
  iInterface              5 
  ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 00 10 01
  ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 01 00 01
  ** UNRECOGNIZED:  04 24 02 00
  ** UNRECOGNIZED:  05 24 06 00 01
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes            3
      Transfer Type            Interrupt
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
    bInterval               9
    bMaxBurst               0
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           2
  bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
  bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              6 
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x8e  EP 14 IN
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
    bInterval               0
    bMaxBurst               2
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x0f  EP 15 OUT
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
    bInterval               0
    bMaxBurst               2
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        2
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           2
  bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
  bInterfaceSubClass     66 
  bInterfaceProtocol      1 
  iInterface              8 
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
    bInterval               0
    bMaxBurst               4
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
    bInterval               0
    bMaxBurst               4
```

**dmesg**

```
[  687.249728] usb usb2: usb_suspend_both: status -16
[  687.274834] usb usb2: usb_suspend_both: status 0
[  687.507536] usb 2-1.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using tegra-xusb
[  687.537647] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=9024
[  687.537663] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  687.537672] usb 2-1.1: Product: SM8150-MTP _SN:D451DCBD
[  687.537680] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: QUALCOMM
[  687.537687] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 4c289fff
```

Comment: Is usb-modeswitch installed? Check: `sudo dpkg -s usb-modeswitch` If not, install it and try again.

Comment: Welcome to [Ubuntu.se]!  **;-)** Please [edit] your question and provide the above relevant info as now **your question is unclear**